# Laravel Filament Logo do not show

Tags: laravel, laravel-filament

Laravel Filament 3, in the AdminPanelProvider

```
->brandLogo(asset('images/Maxis_logo.png'))
```

somehow it produce

'Method Filament\Panel::brandLogo does not exist.'
But the favicon okay it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the below Points

1. Is `images/Maxis_logo.png` located in Public Folder.
2. Recheck if it's loading directly `http://localhost/images/Maxis_logo.png`

Comment: The author of the question states that his error is regarding a non-existent method. That is irrelevant to whether the image file is present at the given location.

Comment: Yes You are correct Sorry my Mistake I was Confused

May I know what is the Filament version you are using. It has been fixed up with the 3.* stabe update